# How can I use JDBC jobstore in Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, quartz

I am trying to configure JDBC jobstore for my Quartz Scheduler application. I have created tables and provided configuration in application.proprties. But the default RAM jobstore is getting initialized.

How should I configure quartz scheduler to use JDBC jobstore.

application.properties

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz_tables
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

##Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update

## QuartzProperties
spring.quartz.job-store-type = jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
spring.quartz.jdbc.schema= classpath:org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_mysql_innodb.sql.class = com.helix.quartz.demo.component.CustomerQuartzInstanceIdGenerator
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 30
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.class = org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.cleanShutdown = TRUE
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2019-06-14 13:35:45.847  INFO 13768 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2019-06-14 13:35:45.847  INFO 13768 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2019-06-14 13:35:45.859  WARN 13768 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX  : Database connection shutdown unsuccessful.

java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'null'
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.shutdown(DBConnectionManager.java:135) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.shutdown(JobStoreSupport.java:746) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.shutdown(QuartzScheduler.java:732) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.shutdownFromInstantiateException(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1411) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1379) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1559) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.createScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:650) [spring-context-support-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.prepareScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:590) [spring-context-support-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:490) [spring-context-support-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.automation.BellIamApplication.main(BellIamApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]

2019-06-14 13:35:45.859  INFO 13768 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
```

Comment: Now it's working fine. I have done the below changes and posted in answer. I had to add spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS as it was taking default null.

Answer (score 3):

Now it's working fine.

I had to mention these configuration in my application.properties file.

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz_tables
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = root
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5


## QuartzProperties

spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 30
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
```

Comment: You could also use `spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.jndiURL` to specify a JNDI datasource, if you use one. It will mean not storing passwords in the properties file.

Answer (score 1):

it works

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore
```